# scatter plot with Sum of unique values in loops in r

Tags: r, loops, plot, label, scatter

I have a set of data generated by different participants who score different visual impairments by giving  value 1-5. (The table has about 2.7k rows)

Column `Participant` is text (50 different IDs), column `Impairment` is text (9 distinctive types), column `Score` is numeric (1-5).

I am trying to generate scatter plots for each `Participant` that display `Score` against `Impairment`. Here is the code I've been using:

```
for (i in unique(Master$Participant)) {
  d <- subset(Master, Master$Participant == i)
  scatter <- ggplot(d, aes(impairment, TechnicalQuality))
  scatter + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..))
}
```

It just won't work.

I tried following code that does work:

```
for (i in unique(Master$Participant)) {
  d <- subset(Master, Master$Participant == i)
  plot(d$impairment, d$TechnicalQuality, type ="p")
}
```

But this is not what I want. (I want label Sum of unique Scores on the scatter plot)

I could't figure out why this first one doesn't work and the second does! Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance

Here are the sample data:

```
M_Participant <- c("A001", "A002", "A010", "B002", "B002", "B003", "A010", "B002")
M_Impairment <- c ("H0", "H1", "H3", "H2",  "H4", "H2", "H3", "H0")
M_Score <- c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1)
Master <- data.frame(Participant = M_Participant, Impairment = M_Impairment,
                     Score= M_Score)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you wrote the code the wrong way for what you want.  Without a reproducible example, that's all I got.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments, I just added sample data at the bottom of the question for your reference.

Comment: @DJay your second plot doesn't work either with the given example. I have the following error: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Comment: In the first block of code, you need to wrap `scatter + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..))` in `print`, i.e.: `print(scatter + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..)))`. Once you've done that, and once you correct the column names (`Impairment`, not `impairment`, and `Score`, not `TechnicalQuality` - assuming your sample data reflect your true data), it should work just fine. In your second block of code, variable names are again incorrect. It's always a good idea to actually _run_ any sample code you provide us with before posting, to ensure it runs without error.

Comment: On another note, if something "just won't work", you should briefly describe what happens, e.g. do you get an error message? do you get a plot that isn't quite what you wanted? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `ggplot` plot call in `print`, which is necessary when generating `ggplot`/`lattice` plots from within a loop or function.

```
for (i in unique(Master$Participant)) {
  d <- subset(Master, Master$Participant == i)
  scatter <- ggplot(d, aes(Impairment, Score))
  print(scatter + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..)))
}
```

Note that you could also do something like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Master, aes(Impairment, Score)) + geom_point()
p + facet_wrap(~ Participant)
```

[image: ggplot]

Or, with `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Score ~ Impairment | Participant, data=Master, pch=20, col=1, 
       scales=list(alternating=FALSE, tck=c(1, 0)))
```

[image: lattice]

Comment: Thanks for all the input by you guys! I run the codes by jbaums and all of them  works great! CHEERS! :-)

Comment: @DJay: You're welcome. You can show your appreciation by upvoting answers that were useful, and if a post solves your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Dear jbaums, I just mark your answer as the accepted answer. Since I am a new user, I don't have enough reputation to vote up. I will do it once I gain enough. Thanks Again!